# IE9 Filters in buttons not showing the value

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Good day community.

I've been trying to style my buttons with CSS to have a nicely gradient inside, it works on all mayor browsers and even in IE8 (to an extent of course), however in IE9 the "value" is not displayed at all so all you can see is an empty button (the gradient does work)

Here's my CSS

```
.button{
    height:28px;
    min-width:150px;
    margin:2px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:bold 10pt ,Arial, Helvetica;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    border:0px solid;
    -moz-border-radius:.3em;
    border-radius:.3em;}

.button-green{                                                      
background:#0B7279;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#23B2B7), to(#0B7279) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #23B2B7, #0B7279);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#23B2B7', endColorstr='#0B7279');}
```

And the HTML to display it:

```
<input class="button button-search" type="button" value="Filter Data" name="search_button" onclick="submitSearch('myValue')">
```

Fiddle: [Button Gradient Test](http://jsfiddle.net/YkdG7/)

Thanks in advance.

PD: Changing the button to an anchor or a clickable div will only be tested if it's the very last resort, otherwise it would be nicer to keep them as inputs.

**EDIT**: The problem seems to be a background image i'm adding to the front of the button with this CSS, the above definition 'button-green' is not being used in this example

```
.button-search{                                                     
padding-left:28px;
background:#0B7279;
background:url(<?php print $images ?>layout/buttonsearch.png) no-repeat left, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#23B2B7), to(#0B7279) );
background:url(<?php print $images ?>layout/buttonsearch.png) no-repeat left, -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, #23B2B7, #0B7279);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#23B2B7', endColorstr='#0B7279'), progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="<?php print $images ?>layout/buttonsearch.png");*/
```

}

Here's the example of what i'm trying to accomplish:

Firefox: [image: button_from_firefox]

IE8: [image: button_from_ie8]

IE9: [image: button_from_ie9]

Answer (score 0):

The old IE-specific `filter` styles are very brittle and have a number of known bugs and glitches.

I can't tell whether what you're describing is a symptom of one of these glitches, but it certainly sounds like it.

In any case I do know that the `filter` gradients will break your `border-radius`; that's a well known bug in IE9, so it's going to look ugly whatever.

My suggestion therefore is to throw away the `filter` style completely. There are other options.

Your first option is to use an SVG image for the background, as a data-URL, as described [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/SVGGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html).

You can keep the `filter` styles for IE8, but use the SVG for IE9. And of course, standard CSS3 gradients for IE10/11.

The above link will generate IE9-specific SVG background for you, which will work exactly as intended. It is a bit of a pain to be carrying all that messy encoded SVG data around though, and it's not easy to work with, so another alternative solution is to use the [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/) script to polyfill support for CSS3 gradients into older IE versions.

This is my preferred solution, because it means you can use standard CSS code for all browsers. Much easier to work with. As a bonus, it also means that your `border-radius` can start working in IE8 as well.

Comment: Oh sorry, i made a couple adjustments to my original post, if you see the jsFiddle you'll see it correctly, the problem seems to be the little image i'm trying to embeed in front. But thanks for your time, if i can't find a solution i'll try this approach